# Prove about the identity component

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need help proving the following statement: Let $G$ be a topological group and $e\in G$ the neutral element, than the identity component $G_0$ is closed. Okay now  I want to show that if $G$ is a locally connected group, so it's identity component is open in G.

Answer (score 0):

Let S be a locally connected space.
For all x in C(a), the component of a,
exists open connected U$_x$ nhood x.
Show U$_x$ subset C(a).
Thus C(a) = $\cup${ U$_x$ : x in C(a) } is open.